# Install Python package inside an IronPython script

Tags: python, installation, ironpython

I want to install a python package inside an IronPython script. I want to write an IronPython script which checks if a package is already installed; if not, the script installs the package.

I tried the following codes:

import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(['pip', 'install', 'package'])

but I get the error: "Win32Exception: WindowsError"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this line of code instead, and it works for me, inside the ironpython script:

```
# replace "package" by package name
!pip install package
```

It installs the package only if missing,
and already handles other cases.

Comment: Actually I had tried your suggestion before. I get the error:
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
I think Alejo Cuartas is right and the system does not recognize pip. I should find the path of pip.

Comment: With any solution, you will need to have the path of pip well defined in environment before running the script

Answer (score 0):

The "WindowsError" you are seeing suggests that the "pip" command is not recognized by your system. This may be because the "pip" command is not in your system's PATH environment variable, or because IronPython is not able to find the "pip" executable.

To fix this issue, you may need to modify your script to explicitly specify the path to the "pip" executable

```
import os
import subprocess

package_name = "package"

# Check if the package is installed
try:
    __import__(package_name)
    print(f"{package_name} is already installed")
except ImportError:
    print(f"{package_name} is not installed")
    
    # Install the package using pip
    pip_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), "Scripts", "pip.exe")
    subprocess.check_call([pip_path, "install", package_name])
```

Comment: I could not find the path of pip. I think pip is not installed. How can I install pip itself?